F11 StepInto just goes to next line in VSCode DEV 1.93.0
I am trying to follow the https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute
steps to Build, to Run, and then to Debug.
I built into  C:\H_Paul\vscode1930   It has product.json "nameShort": "Code - OSS"
and package.json   "name": "code-oss-dev", "version": "1.93.0",
My app (Pencil) has package.json with "main": "index.js", part of index.js is
BP1 L90    var mainUrl = "file://" + __dirname + "/app.xhtml";
BP2 L91    mainWindow.loadURL(mainUrl);
BP3 L92    mainWindow.show();

I then enter BP (breakpoint) on those lines.  And press F5
Expected Result:
When it breaks at Line 91, I want to F11 StepInto vscode1930
and then F10 single step to see whats happening to the app's source code
Actual Result:
But F11 just continues with  Pencil Line92.
Below are launch.json-s for vscode1930 and for Pencil:
//  vscode1930-launch.txt   from  launch.js   expanded for the compound item.
    {
        "name": "VS Code",
        "stopAll": true,
        "debugStdLib":true,
        "configurations": [
            "Launch VS Code Internal",
            "Attach to Main Process",
            "Attach to Extension Host",
            "Attach to Shared Process",
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "Ensure Prelaunch Dependencies",
        "presentation": {
            "group": "0_vscode",
            "order": 1
        }
    },
//====================================================
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch VS Code Internal",
            "windows": {
                "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/scripts/code.bat"
            },
            "osx": {
                "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/scripts/code.sh"
            },
            "linux": {
                "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/scripts/code.sh"
            },
            "port": 9222,
            "timeout": 0,
            "env": {
                "VSCODE_EXTHOST_WILL_SEND_SOCKET": null,
                "VSCODE_SKIP_PRELAUNCH": "1"
            },
            "cleanUp": "wholeBrowser",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--inspect-brk=5875",
                "--no-cached-data",
                "--crash-reporter-directory=${workspaceFolder}/.profile-oss/crashes",
                // for general runtime freezes: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/127861#issuecomment-904144910
                "--disable-features=CalculateNativeWinOcclusion",
                "--disable-extension=vscode.vscode-api-tests"
            ],
            "userDataDir": "${userHome}/.vscode-oss-dev",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "cascadeTerminateToConfigurations": [
                "Attach to Extension Host"
            ],
            "pauseForSourceMap": false,
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
            ],
            "browserLaunchLocation": "workspace",
            "presentation": {
                "hidden": true,
            },
            // This is read by the vscode-diagnostic-tools extension
            "vscode-diagnostic-tools.debuggerScripts": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/scripts/hot-reload-injected-script.js"
            ]
        },
//=========================================
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Main Process",
            "timeout": 30000,
            "port": 5875,
            "continueOnAttach": true,
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
            ],
            "presentation": {
                "hidden": true,
            }
        },
//=========================================
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "restart": true,
            "name": "Attach to Extension Host",
            "timeout": 0,
            "port": 5870,
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js",
                "${workspaceFolder}/extensions/*/out/**/*.js"
            ]
        },
//=========================================
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "restart": true,
            "name": "Attach to Shared Process",
            "timeout": 0,
            "port": 5879,
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
            ]
        },
//=========================================
// Pencil launch.json
{
    "justMyCode": false,
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Electron: Main",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
            "windows": {
                "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd"
            },
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "."
            ],
            "trace": true,            
            "env": {
                "VSCODE_DEBUG_MODE": "true"
            },
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "outputCapture": "std",  
            "outFiles": [ "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js" ],  
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}

